# Segmentation fault on cvReleaseImage() after assigning data with SetData()

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to acquire single images from a camera, do some processing to them and release the used memory. I've been doing it for quite some time with a code similar to the one that follows:

```
char* img_data = new char[ len ]; // I retrieve len from the camera.

// Grab the actual image from the camera: 
// It fills the previous buffer with the image data.
// It gives width and height.

CvSize size;
size.width = width;
size.height = height;
IplImage* img = cvCreateImageHeader( size, 8, 1 );
img->imageData = img_data;

// Do the processing

cvReleaseImage( &img );
```

This code runs fine. I have recently read [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#iplimage) (in the imageData description) that I shouldn't be assigning data directly to img->imageData but use SetData() instead, like so:

```
cvSetData( img, img_data, width );
```

However, when I do it like this, I get a Segmentation fault at the cvReleaseImage() call.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I have tried to compile and run the program that @karlphillip suggested and I DO get a segmentation fault using cvSetData but it runs fine when assigning the data directly.
I'm using Debian 6 and OpenCV 2.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well, but believe it was fixed from what I gathered in
[this comment](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/c-cvReleaseImage-tp2415881p2417169.html); namely to use cvReleaseImageHeader() and not cvReleaseImage().

For example:

```
unsigned int width = 100;
unsigned int height = 100;
unsigned int channels = 1;
unsigned char* imageData = (unsigned char*)malloc(width*height*channels);
// set up the image data

IplImage *img = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, channels);
cvSetData(img, imageData, width*channels); 

// use img

cvReleaseImageHeader(&img);

// free(imageData) when finished
```

Comment: Nice! This fixed the problem, but it's still weird that cvReleaseImage fails on GNU/Linux and not on Mac OS X. I sent an e-mail at the OpenCV mailing list but it's not getting accepted (maybe I can't post links to external websites or something). Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah in OpenCV 3.1.0 it worked on macOS Sierra but now I porting app to Windows Cygwin environment and it crash with segmantation fault!

Comment: Using cvReleaseImageHeader on Cygiwn I still have such error "openCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 893 "

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are allocating memory the C++ way (using `new`), while using the C interface of OpenCV, which tries to free that memory block with `free()` inside `cvReleaseImage()`. Memory allocations of C and C++ can't be mixed together.

Solution: use `malloc()` to allocate the memory:

```
char* img_data = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char)); 
// casting the return of malloc might not be necessary 
// if you are using a C++ compiler
```

**EDIT:** (due to OP's comment that is still crashing)

**Something else** that you are not showing us is crashing your application! I seriously recommend that you write a complete/minimal application that reproduces the problem you are having.

The following application works fine in my Mac OS X with OpenCV 2.3.1.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main()
{
    char* img_data = (char*) malloc(625); 

    CvSize size;
    size.width = 25;
    size.height = 25;
    IplImage* img = cvCreateImageHeader( size, 8, 1 );

    //img->imageData = img_data;
    cvSetData( img, img_data, size.width );

    cvReleaseImage( &img );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right. I should be using the C++ interface of OpenCV, really :). This, however, hasn't solved the segmentation fault.

Comment: It hasn't solved the crash because there's some other code in your application that is causing it and you are not sharing it with us. I updated answer to show you that it works, and **we can't help you any further unless you write a compilable-minimal-application that reproduces the behavior you are observing**.

Comment: I was about to try to write a little program like the one you suggested to see if it worked. Once I have access to the same machine I'll update the question with the results. Thank you!

Comment: The compilable-minimal-application you posted also crashes. Could this be a bug in OpenCV 2.3.1 for Linux?

Comment: Interesting. I just tested this code on my Fedora box and it crashed. This might be an OpenCV bug. I suggest you send an email to OpenCV mailing list and share this question with them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you allocate a header and set data manually, you should deallocate *only* the header and free the data yourself:

```
// allocate img_data

IplImage* img = cvCreateImageHeader( size, 8, 1 );
img->imageData = img_data;
cvReleaseImageHeader( &img ); // frees only the header

// free img_data
```

If you call cvReleaseImage, it will also try to free the data, so you then rely on the OpenCV implementation to do it, which failed in your case because it uses `free` and you allocated with `new` which are incompatible with each other.
The other option is to allocate with `malloc` and call `cvReleaseImage`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a detail to this discussion. There seems to be some sort of bug in
cvReleaseHeader() function.
**You have to release the header first and then free the image data.**
If you do it the other way, i.e., free image data and then call cvReleaseHeader() function, then it *deceptively* works. But internally it leaks memory and after sometime your application will crash.